# Calling Delete Service not working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

**ListStore.ts file**

```
export class ListstoreComponent implements OnInit {
  rawlist;
  name = '';
  id = '';
  storeid = "";
  store: Store;

  constructor(private api: APIService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private cookieService: CookieService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storelist();

  }

  //store list
  async storelist() {
    this.rawlist = await this.api.ListStores();
    this.storelist = this.rawlist.items;
  }
  //delete list
  async deleteStore(id) {
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete?')){
    await this.api.DeleteStore(id).catch(data => {
      this.rawlist();
    })
  }
}
```

**HTML File**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-gap" (click)="deleteStore(Store.id)">Close Ticket</button>
```

I'm deleting the list and updating database. But I am not quite sure if catch() would work or not. I've tried subscribe but didn't work

Comment: What is the return type of `this.api.DeleteStore(id)` ?

Comment: @KurtHamilton you mean string or number? here id is string

Comment: No. The function. Is it Observable, a Promise, something else?

Comment: @KurtHamilton a promise

Comment: You should use .then

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler should handle the async nature of the call rather than leaking it up to the HTML.

```
deleteStore(id): void {
  if (!window.confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete?')){
    return;
  }

  this.api.DeleteStore(id).then(message => {
    // handle response
  });
}
```

Edit:

You could handle it in the HTML, but you would have to return a promise from your event handler, and you would end up with more code in you HTML than there should be.

If you're really keen to use the `async` `await` syntax, the following would be equivalent:

```
async deleteStore(id): void {
  if (!window.confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete?')){
    return;
  }

  const message = await this.api.DeleteStore(id);
  // handle response
}
```

Comment: `async deleteStore(id) {
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete?')){
    this.api.DeleteStore(id).then(message => {
      this.storelist()
    })
  }
  
} `

is it something like that?

Comment: No need to use async if you're using `.then`. I've updated my answer with an await / async example

Comment: `deleteStore(id) {
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete?')){
    this.api.DeleteStore(id).then(data => {
      console.log(id)
   })
  }
}`

in handle response I am returning the id

Comment: I am getting this following error
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"data":null,"errors":[{"path":null,"locations":[{"line":1,"column":22,"sourceName":null}],"message":"Variable 'input' has an invalid value. Expected type 'Map' but was 'String'. Variables for input objects must be an instance of type 'Map'."}]}`

Comment: That's not really related to this question. Your question was about how to call a promise from a button click. The error message is pretty clear about the fact that you should be providing a `Map` instead of a string, but that could be anywhere in your code.